# useSWRMutation stale state in onSuccess callback expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, swr

When I console.log `phoneNumber` in `onSuccess`, it shows an empty string instead of the correct value. `phoneNumber` is stale. When I type something in my editor which makes the app rerender, `phoneNumber` has the correct value. It seems the function in `onSuccess` sort of gets captured by the closure for some reason? I'm not sure why.

```js
const verifyPhoneNumber = async (url: string, { arg: phoneNumber }) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        phone_number: phoneNumber,
      }),
    });
    const json = await response.json();
    return json;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};

const SignUp = (props: Props) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState("");

  const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/";

  // const url = "http://192.168.0.142:8000/user/auth/otp-code/";

  const { trigger, isMutating } = useSWRMutation(url, verifyPhoneNumber, {
    onSuccess: () => {
      // The problem is here, phoneNumber is an empty string
      console.log(phoneNumber)
      navigation.navigate("VerifyCode", {
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      });
    },
    onError: (error) => console.log(error),
  });

  const sendOTP = () => {
    trigger(phoneNumber);
  };
  // phoneNumber shows the proper string
  console.log(phoneNumber);

  return (
    <AppBox>
      <InputFieldForAuth
        inputIsInvalid={false}
        value={phoneNumber}
        onChangeText={(newText: string) => setPhoneNumber(newText)}
        placeholder={`Enter your phone number here`}
      />
      </HyperlinkText>
      <Button
        text="Continue"
        onPress={sendOTP}
      />
    </AppBox>
  );
};
```

I even tried something like this to make the function get recreated with a new `phoneNumber` each render, and `phoneNumber` is still stale

```js
 const onSuccess = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(phoneNumber);
    navigation.navigate("VerifyCode", {
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
    });
  }, [phoneNumber]);

  const { trigger, isMutating } = useSWRMutation(url, verifyPhoneNumber, {
    onSuccess: onSuccess,
    onError: (error) => console.log(error),
  });
```

A snack is attached at the bottom demonstrating the issue.

https://snack.expo.dev/@meg_hidey/uplifting-churros